# Passing WebResponse Byte Array to function to extract image

Tags: vb.net, image, arrays

There are many suggestions for using the Image.FromStream(stream) on the Internet and look like they should do what I want. However, there is just one piece I don't fully understand.

I am making a GET request to a URL that returns a Byte Array which is an image. I make the request and get the response like this:

```
Public Function getPic(ByRef stu As String) As Image

    Dim url As String = "myurl" & stu 'identifying number I am adding to the url
    Dim hwrequest As HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    hwrequest.Method = "Get"

    Dim hwresponse = hwrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    hwresponse.CopyTo(ms)
    Dim img As Image
    img = Image.FromStream(ms)

    PictureBox1.Image = img

End Function
```

I have found two different code suggestions:

```
Public Function byteArrayToImage(ByVal byteArrayIn As Byte()) As Image
    Using mStream As New MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)
        Return Image.FromStream(mStream)
End Function
```

Here I understand I need to pass the Byte Array from my response to the function but that is where my understanding is lacking. When I pass in

```
 Public Function byteArrayToImage(ByVal hwresponse As Byte()) As Image
    Using mStream As New MemoryStream(hwresponse)
        Return Image.FromStream(mStream)
```

I get "Value of Stream cannot be converted to Byte"

When I try this code:

```
Private Function BytesToImage(hwresponse AS Stream) As Image
Dim imgNew As Image
Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream(hwresponse)
imgNew = Image.FromStream(memImage)
Return imgNew
```

End Function

I get "Parameter not valid" on Image.fromStream.

I am not understanding how to take my WebResponse and pass it to the function correctly to extract the image

Comment: In your last code block, are you sure there isn't an error on `Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream(hwresponse)`?  I don't see a constructor for [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes another stream.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is and why you need `byteArrayToImage`.  The code of your `getPic` method will retrieve an image even though the function itself is incomplete to return an image.

Comment: Your Functions with the `Using` statement are missing the `End Using`  Also you should show complete code.   Show the code where you are actually making the call to those Functions.

Comment: TnTinMn  - What is the incomplete part? That is what I need help with. That's the code I'm using. The code that calls is is simply passing the value 'stu' to the function, and I'm trying to get the image and place it on a windows form.

Comment: Here's my complete code I'm testing with